# The column label 'national_id' is not unique

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe but when I use this :

```
total_views.columns = [['national_id','total_views']]
ret.columns = [['national_id','count']]
merged_df = ret.merge(total_views, on= 'national_id')
```

I got this error "The column label 'national_id' is not unique"
[image]
but when I use this one :

```
total_views.columns = ['national_id','total_views']
ret.columns = ['national_id','count']
merged_df = ret.merge(total_views, on= 'national_id')
```

my code work properly
I can't find any difference between one bracket or two brackets
[image]

I try figure out what's difference between this 2 syntaxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using double square brackets creates a MultiIndex for the columns which is why you get your error.  If you run `total_views.columns` after running the lines of code to rename columns using double brackets, you get:

```
MultiIndex([('national_id',),
            ('total_views',)],
           )
```

Whereas running it after renaming the columns using single square brackets gives a normal index:

```
Index(['national_id', 'total_views'], dtype='object')
```